# How to make an Analytics App

Tags: xcode, instagram

I see that there are all these analytics apps for FB, Instagram, Twitter, etc.. that track your top followers/who unfollowed you etc.... and I was wondering how can you make something like this. How do you get access to Instagram. All the apps out there charge people a ton of money and being an David instagram user, I hate it. I want to make my ow app that is a 1 time fee of $1 and I don't want to rope people's arms for cash. I am a programmer so I was hoping to make the app in Xcode. I just need to know how to import follower/likes etc.. into my app from individual instagram accounts.

Thanks!

Comment: While this question is too broad for SO, check out OAuth and the individual API documentation pages for the social networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the various app's api's. You can google each of the app's apis where you want to pull data from and use the data in your app.